# How often are state constitutional amendments overturned by federal judges?

Tags: united-states, constitution, us-state-laws

I live in a state in the United States that just had a constitutional amendment that I voted for overturned by a federal judge and am suitably ticked.

How often does this happen to American citizens and what can the average person do to appeal a law that they believe they have a stake in that was overturned by a federal judge?  Does a citizen have grounds for appealing a constitutional amendment that was overturned by virtue of the fact that they voted for it?

Comment: I'm assuming from timing that you're [in Wisconsin](http://www.jsonline.com/news/statepolitics/federal-judge-overturns-wisconsins-gay-marriage-ban-b99286138z1-262161851.html)?  It matters because it determines what basis the judge has, although the issue itself is irrelevant.

Comment: @Bobson I think the judge had a big long-winded opinion.  Is that her basis?

Comment: Generally, you only have grounds to appeal a ruling if you were somehow involved in the original case.

Comment: @SamIam I'd think that the act of voting for the law that was overturned should make someone involved.  Pretty lame if that's not the case.

Comment: @PeterTurner - Alright, I *think* I addressed everything in my answer, except for "how often".  Let me know if you need more clarification on anything.

Answer (score 10):

The main reason I know of for a federal judge to step in when it comes to state laws is when those laws are unconstitutional.  For instance, if a state passed a law, or even an amendment to its state constitution which permitted slavery, the federal judge could overturn it as a violation of the [13th amendment](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Additional_amendments_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Amendment_XIII).

Federal judges have this power, because of [Article VI](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_United_States_of_America#Article._VI.) of the US Consitution wihch reads (in part):

> This Constitution, and the Laws of the United States which shall be made in Pursuance thereof; and all Treaties made, or which shall be made, under the Authority of the United States, shall be the supreme Law of the Land; and the Judges in every State shall be bound thereby, **any Thing in the Constitution or Laws of any state to the Contrary notwithstanding.**

In [Article III](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_United_States_of_America#Article._III.), it specifies that

> The judicial Power of the United States, shall be vested in one supreme Court, and in such inferior Courts as the Congress may from time to time ordain and establish.

Taken together, this means that when a state passes an unconstitutional law, it is itself breaking the law (Article VI), and can be taken before a federal court (Article III) to be forced to change its course (you can't exactly arrest a state, after all).  And the US Supreme Court (SCOTUS) determines what is unconstitutional.

---

So much for the general case.  In this example, which I am assuming is related to Wisconsin's gay marriage ban being overturned, SCOTUS has found that laws restricting gay marriage are a violation of the [Fifth Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Equal_liberty)'s "Due Process" clause, which says (in part):

> nor shall any person ... be deprived of life, liberty, or property, without due process of law

In *[Windsor v. United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windsor_v._United_States)* they held that laws defining marriage as between one man and one woman violate a homosexual's rights to equal liberty (specifically, to marry who they choose).  Since these laws are now unconstitutional, and the US Constitution is the supreme law of the land, all state-level laws (and constitutional amendments) are now illegal, and thus they legally *must* be overturned.

---

As for addressing it, in *[Hollingsworth v. Perry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollingsworth_v._Perry#Details_of_the_ruling)* SCOTUS decided that you don't have standing to sue the government for its decisions simply because you voted for or championed a given cause.  The details are on that wikipedia page, but it boils down to this (my interpretation): "If you can't show how you, personally, were or will be harmed by the law, you can't sue to stop it.

Basically, unless the ability of other people to marry has some detrimental affect on your legal rights, you have no standing to sue.

*However,* as @cpast pointed out in the comments, the state itself *does* have standing to appeal (assuming it wants to, which California didn't in *Hollingsworth v. Perry*), because it is directly affected by this ruling, so you can encourage your governor to pursue it on your (and the state's) behalf.

Comment: Note that, even though no individual Wisconsinite has standing to sue or file an appeal, the state government _does_ have standing to appeal. In _Perry_, the state of California refused to defend the amendment at all; in trial court, a third party could intervene and try to defend the amendment, but when they lost, they didn't have standing to file their _own_ motion appealing the decision, and California certainly wasn't going to appeal for them. In Wisconsin, though, it looks like the state _is_ likely to appeal, so it'll get heard by a higher court anyways.

Comment: @cpast - Very good point.  I've added a mention of that in to the answer.

Comment: This is a great answer but i still want to know if any other constitutional amendments added by referendum have been overturned, if that has never happened in the history of the USA, then this would be a pretty blatant attack on self-governance.

Comment: @PeterTurner - [Here is an example](http://ballotpedia.org/Oklahoma_%22Sharia_Law_Amendment%22,_State_Question_755_(2010)) of a approved-by-ballot state constitutional amendment which was overturned by the 10th Circuit Court Of Appeals.  [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Proposition_14_(1964)) is an older example of one that got overturned by the *state* Supreme Court, then had that ruling affirmed by the SCOTUS.  So it's happened via both the state court system and the federal court system in the past.  I couldn't find the *first* instance of it, though.

Comment: Also, it's not just the US Constitution that state laws must comply with; a federal statute or regulation also trumps anything in a state law or a state constitution (e.g. an FCC licensee can operate according to their federal license, even if a state passes a constitutional amendment requiring a state license).

Comment: @cpast - Actually, state law trumps federal laws unless the latter is in a sphere where the Constitution grants power to Congress or takes it away from the states themselves (See the 10th Amendment).  That said, the Commerce Clause has been used to authorize a huge amount of federal legislation, including the creation of the FCC (which then has been granted authority to pass its own rules that carry the force of the laws which created it).

Comment: @Bobson No, state law never trumps federal. The feds have either supreme authority on a topic or no authority on the topic; a valid federal law is always supreme over all state law. If a federal law isn't pursuant to the constitution, it's not a law at all (whether or not a state law conflicts), so that's not state law trumping federal. If it is, it trumps any state law.

Comment: To clarify what I'm trying to say: Your examples have state constitutional amendments doing something that the Constitution explicitly bars a state government from doing (mostly 14th Amendment). But if Congress chooses to exercise its powers in a certain (otherwise legal) way, that statute trumps any state constitution; state constitutions aren't more protected against preemption than state laws are, and preemption doesn't require a direct conflict with the Constitution (valid federal laws, even if not *required* by the constitution, trump any state law).

Comment: @cpast - I think we're saying the same thing, just approaching it from two different sides.  You're saying that a *valid* federal law trumps state laws and constitutions, and I'm saying that a federal law which doesn't derive from the Constitution in some way, can't.  To be fair, Congress can pass anything they feel like passing - but if the state whose law would be overturned objected and went to court over it, that's when it would be ruled an invalid overreach.  I'll admit that my phrasing wasn't the best - "trumps" was probably the wrong word to use there.

Answer (score -4):

"How often" would be difficult to find a quantitative answer for, but this is not a strange occurrence. The structures of some states allow the collective will of the people to establish the framework of that state more directly than others, yet there is no framework in the United States' structure to support the will of the people if they violate the constitution of the republic.

So it is always perplexing to see people waste their energy on certain things in a political way, but maybe within those areas the concept is not so readily understood or maybe there is a lot of social pressure to support certain political goals.

Comment: (protip: just because it is downvoted does not mean it is incorrect)

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean that it's incorrect, but it *does* mean people think it doesn't answer the question.  Personally, I have no idea what you're saying here.

Comment: I think time is the only barrier to finding out a quantitative answer. It would only take somebody annotating each Supreme Court decision as to whether it overturned a state constitutional amendment, and then reporting that.